# Number of decimal digits to show

Tags: matlab, format

How to change the number of decimal digits? 
Changing the `format` Matlab can show only 4 (if `short`) or 15 (if `long`). But I want exactly 3 digits to show.

Comment: use `sprintf`? e.g. `sprintf('%f.3', YourVarible)`

Comment: There is no built-in format to do what you want, so Dan's workaround is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `sprintf` or do *

```
var2 = round(var1*1000)/1000
```

Comment: It will change the number in the memory, but I don't want it. I want just to show another amount of digits

Comment: Then you can just do another_var = round(var*1000)/1000.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Hamataro's answer, you could also use `roundn` function to round to a specific decimal precision, e.g.: `roundn(1.23456789,-3)` will yield `1.235`. However, Matlab will still display the result in either of the formats you have mentioned, i.e `1.2350` if format is set to short, and `1.235000000000000` if format is set for long.

Alternatively, if you use `sprintf`, you can use the `%g` formatting option to display only a set number of digits, regardless of where the decimal point is. `sprintf('%0.3g',1.23456789)` yields `1.23`; `sprintf('%0.3g',12.3456789)` yields `12.3`